# Mysql: Get the max value with corrsponding time and group by day

Tags: mysql, datetime, max

My table is:

```
timelog              | roomtemp  
2014-07-14 01:16:04  | 25.0    |
2014-07-14 02:14:05  | 26.0    |
2014-07-14 03:13:05  | 25.0    |
2014-07-14 05:13:11  | 29.0    |
2014-07-14 06:15:05  | 25.0    |
2014-07-14 07:17:13  | 30.0    |
       .
       .
2014-07-15 01:13:05  | 25.0    |
2014-07-15 01:16:04  | 31.0    |
2014-07-15 02:14:05  | 25.0    |
2014-07-15 03:13:05  | 28.0    |
2014-07-15 05:13:05  | 25.0    |
```

I want to get the max(roomtemp) with corresponding timelog for each day
such as:

```
2014-07-14 07:17:13  | 30.0    |
2014-07-15 01:16:04  | 31.0    |
```

I tired following for 2014-07-14, but fail~:

```
$sql="SELECT timelog, MAX(roomtemp) FROM $tablename WHERE timelog BETWEEN '2014-07-14 00:00:00' AND '2014-07-14 23:59:59' ";<p>
$result=mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die("ERR201: Error");
```

It shows error message

I can get the maximum roomtemp if I delete timelog which after SELECT

```
$sql="SELECT MAX(roomtemp) FROM $tablename WHERE timelog BETWEEN '2014-07-14 00:00:00' AND '2014-07-14 23:59:59' ";<p>
$result=mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die("ERR201: Error");
```

I also tried group by DAY(timelog), but timelog value is not correct...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Query to get day and max temperature on that day:**

```
select date(timelog) as day,max(roomtemp) from table_name group by day;
```

Output:

[image]

**Query to get time and max temerature on a day:**

```
SELECT timelog AS curr_day,MAX(roomtemp) FROM (SELECT * FROM day_temperature ORDER BY roomtemp DESC) c GROUP BY DATE(curr_day);
```

Output:

[image]

SQL dump:

```
/*
SQLyog Ultimate v10.00 Beta1
MySQL - 5.5.24-log 
*********************************************************************
*/
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

create table `day_temperature` (
    `timelog` datetime ,
    `roomtemp` float 
); 
insert into `day_temperature` (`timelog`, `roomtemp`) values('2014-07-19 10:27:20','25');
insert into `day_temperature` (`timelog`, `roomtemp`) values('2014-07-19 10:30:21','27');
insert into `day_temperature` (`timelog`, `roomtemp`) values('2014-07-20 11:10:20','28');
insert into `day_temperature` (`timelog`, `roomtemp`) values('2014-07-20 12:00:00','23');
```

Comment: Thanks! How about if I want to get the timelog with time hour: min:second , not only date?

Comment: Ok looking on that will provide that solution also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATE()` to extract date from a datetime:

```
SELECT DATE(timelog), MAX(room_temp) FROM $tablename GROUP BY DATE(timelog)
```